# pl/sql updateXML must be declared

Tags: plsql

I am trying to insert into an xmltype something, I read the oracle docs and it says I should use updateXML or insertChildXML, but the compler says, updateXML must be declared

searched everywhere but i cant find any reference to missing functions
I am using the 11g, as a must, this is the start of a very long assignment and i can't do much without the functions to modify xmltype

Help, how do I solve that compiler error?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE comentar_evento
(
    id_usuario IN NUMBER, 
    id_lugar IN NUMBER, 
    nombre_evento IN VARCHAR2, 
    comentario IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
otag VARCHAR2(50); 
ctag VARCHAR2(50);
xmlPath VARCHAR2(50);
xpEnd VARCHAR2(50);
ag XMLType;
BEGIN
    otag := '<comentario>';
    ctag := '</comentario>';
    xmlPath := '/agenda/evento/[nombre_evento="';
    xpEnd := '"]/comentarios';
    xmlPath := xmlPath || nombre_evento || xpEnd;

    SELECT agenda INTO ag FROM usuario WHERE id = id_usuario;

    insertChildXML(ag, xmlPath, 'comentario', otag || comentario || ctag);
END;
/
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb04cre.htm#ADXDB0400

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but from the documentation it appears to be a function, not a procedure as in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the documentation again.
Doc reads as "INSERTCHILDXML SQL Function".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE comentar_evento
(
    id_usuario IN NUMBER, 
    id_lugar IN NUMBER, 
    nombre_evento IN VARCHAR2, 
    comentario IN VARCHAR2
)
IS
otag VARCHAR2(50); 
ctag VARCHAR2(50);
xmlPath VARCHAR2(50);
xpEnd VARCHAR2(50);
ag XMLType;
v_result xmltype;
BEGIN
    otag := '<comentario>';
    ctag := '</comentario>';
    xmlPath := '/agenda/evento/[nombre_evento="';
    xpEnd := '"]/comentarios';
    xmlPath := xmlPath || nombre_evento || xpEnd;

    SELECT agenda INTO ag FROM usuario WHERE id = id_usuario;

    v_result := insertChildXML(ag, xmlPath, 'comentario', otag || comentario || ctag);
END;
/
```

Comment: So every function in pl/sql must return something?, i am too used to other languages, Thank you tho, =,)

Comment: Yeah.that's the difference between a procedure and function. I function is compelled to return a value. If you find the answer useful then please mark it an answer and upvote it.